# Using AppleScript to read code from AppleScript file (.scpt)

Tags: applescript, readfile

I would like to get the code from an AppleScript file (.scpt) using AppleScript. I tried the obvious:

```
set the_file to choose file -- Assume the user chooses a .scpt file
read the_file
```

However, the result I get if I select a script like this (as seen on AppleScript Editor):

[image]

is this:

```
"FasdUAS 1.101.10ˇˇˇˇ
k
lˇ˛ˇ˛;5 By Richard Kulesus, 2009.  Released without license!±     j By Richard Kulesus, 2009.  Released without license!


lˇ˝
ˇ˝ Use this for whatever!
±. Use this for whatever!
lˇ¸ˇ¸OI I seriously despise code authors who copyright tiny bits of obvious code±í I seriously despise code authors who copyright tiny bits of obvious code
lˇ˚ˇ˚PJ like it's some great treasure.  This is small and simple, and if it saves±î like it's some great treasure.  This is small and simple, and if it saves
lˇ˙ˇ˙LF the next guy some time and trouble coding applescript I'll feel good!±å the next guy some time and trouble coding applescript I'll feel good!
lˇ˘ˇ¯ˇ˜ˇ˘ˇ¯ˇ˜ !
 lˇˆ\"#ˇˆ\">8 Quickly change all the hot-corners to do what you want.#±$$p Quickly change all the hot-corners to do what you want.!%&
%lˇı'(ˇı'C= Particularly useful for presentations and full-screen games.(±))z Particularly useful for presentations and full-screen games.&*+
```

(etc)

and not this:

```
-- By Richard Kulesus, 2009.  Released without license!
-- Use this for whatever!
-- I seriously despise code authors who copyright tiny bits of obvious code
-- like it's some great treasure.  This is small and simple, and if it saves
-- the next guy some time and trouble coding applescript I'll feel good!
--
-- Quickly change all the hot-corners to do what you want.
```

(etc)

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way I ran into, though probably no more acceptable, since the `osadecompile` utility is invoked:

```
set scriptContent to do shell script "osadecompile " & quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    set myScript to open (choose file)
    set scriptContent to (text of myScript) as text
    close myScript
    log scriptContent
end tell
```

Comment: Yes, I knew something like that would work but I would prefer not to have to open any application.

Comment: @Alex - `set myScript to load script (choose file)` looks promising - the script editor displays the loaded script in the "Replies" tab, but so far I haven't figured out how to get this text into a variable.